# How to combine two uproot jagged arrays into one

Tags: uproot, awkward-array

I am using uproot with awkward-array and have two jagged arrays containing the list of electrons per event and muons per event.  How can I combine these to get the list of leptons per event i.e. concatenate the inner axis

E.g. I have

```py
<JaggedArray [[30.124887 8.12566 4.782032 ... 3.4062831 4.03435 1.9781811] [19.604109 14.973876 6.788245 ... 3.8568115 2.8912365 1.643329] [94.34076 9.03234 8.532933 ... 5.3950877 5.4614944 4.3668523] ... [38.562923 12.081268 13.118397 ... 4.6826 9.002948 9.387798] [57.30162 40.492176 16.799332 ... 2.3019862 2.7607398 1.1167078] [44.25976 49.21996 25.044079 ... 2.7800367 2.2228014 1.9305638]] at 0x00013e6c5b90>
```

and

```py
 <JaggedArray [[18.414927 27.532492 52.004097 171.83276 13.92745 112.39277] [39.092228 12.521418 550.6525 14.215196] [2.4486308 22.593899] ... [52.05381 2.8950057 3.3865757 ... 56.505566 8.103792 5.061536] [2.3811734 2.2230856 3.4453635 15.346841] []] at 0x00013bf7e350>
```

and the output I want is something like

```py
<JaggedArray [[30.124887 8.12566 4.782032 ... 3.4062831 4.03435 1.9781811 18.414927 27.532492 52.004097 171.83276 13.92745 112.39277] [[19.604109 14.973876 6.788245 ... 3.8568115 2.8912365 1.643329 39.092228 12.521418 550.6525 14.215196] []] >
```

Cheers,

Carl

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `awkward.concatenate` with `axis=1` (inner lists), as opposed to the default `axis=0` (outer list).

You lose the identities of the particles—which were electrons and which were mins, but unless you apply complex filters, you can reconstruct them with the `counts` of the original jagged arrays.

Comment: I should have been clearer that I am doing this with the result of zipping JaggedArrays and I get:

```
NotImplementedError: concatenate with axis=1 is not implemented for JaggedArray

```

Comment: This is a misleading error message—it's raised inside the implementation of `concatenate` with `axis=1` for JaggedArrays: https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward-array/blob/f1b4a3473c3eac5a1919565be4e9a0681611204b/awkward/array/jagged.py#L1707 I see your case implemented in the `if` statements above it: JaggedArrays of numbers are definitely included. Could you report a minimal reproducing example in GitHub Issues?

Comment: Done.  Thanks.  https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward-array/issues/205

Comment: Thanks! From your example, I can see that you're not concatenating `JaggedArrays` of numbers (your original question), which `awkward.concatenate` already handles. Your case _should_ be handled, and I added a PR. (For future readers of this, follow the link above.)